# Apache Common Math's Fraction to Double

Tags: java, apache, math

**Introduction**

setComputerizedFractionAnswer

```
private void setComputerizedFractionAnswer(double randomDigitOne,
        double randomDigitTwo, MathematicalOperator mathematicalOperator) {

    this.computerizedFractionAnswer = fraction(randomDigitOne).add(
            fraction(randomDigitTwo));
}
```

getComputerizedFractionAnswer

```
private Fraction getComputerizedFractionAnswer() {
    return computerizedFractionAnswer;
}
```

A Double or Fraction answer will be posted from a servlet and subsequently the following method will be called:

```
public String validateAnswer(double d) {
    if (getComputerizedAnswer() == d || getComputerizedFractionAnswer() == d) {
        return "Correct";
    }
    return "Wrong";
}
```

which causes the following issue:

`Incompatible operand types Fraction and double`.

Based on [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html) and [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/FractionFormat.html) information it is unclear how to convert a Fraction type into Double.

**Question**

It is possible to convert Apache Common Math's Fraction into Double?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/Fraction.html#doubleValue%28%29 how about that? Or just do the conversion yourself, I'd assume you can get the top and bottom and convert those to doubles.

Comment: @Ben Perhaps you could post the comment as an answer, as it answers the question.

Comment: You didn't say anything for so long I didn't know if that's what you wanted and if it worked lol. But done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per utrecht's suggestion, for future references:

From the API here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/Fraction.html#doubleValue%28%29, `Fraction`s have a member method `doubleValue()`.